# Postgres Pattern Match on Multiple Substring Options

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, I have a column in a table which stores the User Agent (browser info) as a VARCHAR.

I need to run a Postgres query which in JavaScript could be accomplished as

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // ....
}
```

Is it possible to do a quick query without listing a `LIKE` on each substring?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't let me list options as an OR, only a *~ within a given string.

Comment: It lists `|`, which is the same in pretty much every regexp implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

```
WITH cte(col) AS (
  VALUES ('Android'),('webOS'),('iPhone'),('iPad') -- ...
)
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM table t
JOIN cte
  ON t.user_agent LIKE '%' || cte.col || '%';
```